# Read file content throws cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I want to read html template from resources folder into JUnit file. I tried this:

```
        String resourceName = "templates/account_confirmation.html";

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(resourceName).getFile());

        String content = Files.readString(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I get error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)
  location: class java.nio.file.Files
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You can read resources which are under test and I assume account_confirmation.html is in your main resource folder under src/main/java and not under src/test/java

Answer (score 0):

This was introduced in Java 11. Make sure the environment running it is using Java 11.

Comment: Yes, I configure that already but it's not working.